# How to print a string from an array in c?

Tags: arrays, c, list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    enum months {JAN = 1, FB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER};
    printf(months{2}));//This line shows error
}
```

Comment: There are no strings in your code. And there is one excess `)`  in the line with `printf`, and there is no such thing as `months{2}` in C. [Edit] and confirm your desired output here is `MAR`. And learn how to format questions, it only takes a few minutes.

Comment: I guess you may want to have an `enum` of month values and a way to convert an `enum` value to a string. Please clarify this in your question. Arrays in C start with index 0, so it may be easier to chieve this when your `enum` starts with 0, so either change it to `JAN = 0` or use an additional value something like `_INVALID = 0, JAN, ...`

Comment: There are neither strings or arrays in this code, so what exactly is the question here?

Comment: I suggest the question title should be something like "How to print an enum value as a string".

Comment: @Bodo Don't guess, ask for clarification and vote to close as unclear until that happens.

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no way to print an enum as a string.

You'll have to do it in another way.

For instance:

```
char* months[] = {"ILLEGAL", "JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN",
                             "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"};

printf("%s", months[2]);  // Will print FEB
```

(notice that arrays in C start from index zero so in order to make index 1 contain "JAN", a dummy element must be added before "JAN")

Alternatively you can print it using:

```
puts(months[2]);  // Will print FEB followed by a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use enum and print is as a string you can do something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum months { JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC};

const char* getmonth(enum months month)
{
    switch(month)
    {
        case JAN:
            return "JAN";
        case FEB:
            return "FEB";
        //....
        case DEC:
            return "DEC";
        default:
            return "Error";
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s",getmonth(FEB) );
}
```

output:

```
FEB
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In C you cannot automatically convert an `enum` value to a string that corresponds to the textual form of the `enum` value. You need a separate array of strings.

If you want to define both the `enum` type and the strings without typing the names twice (which is error prone) you can use preprocessor macros.
This advanced technique is called [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).
You could also use this technique to construct a `switch`-`case` solution as shown in other answers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MONTHS(F) \
    F(_INVALID) \
    F(JAN) \
    F(FEB) \
    F(MAR) \
    F(APR) \
    F(MAY) \
    F(JUN) \
    F(JUL) \
    F(AUG) \
    F(SEP) \
    F(OCT) \
    F(NOV) \
    F(DEC) \
    F(_MAX)

#define CASE(X) case X: name = #X; break;

int main(void)
{
    /* construct enum using macro */
    enum months {
        MONTHS(ENUMVAL)
    };

    /* construct corresponding strings array using macro */
    const char *month_strings[] = {
        MONTHS(STRING)
    };

    /* array based solution */
    printf("month_strings[2] %s\n", month_strings[2]);
    printf("month_strings[MAY] %s\n", month_strings[MAY]);
    printf("\n");

    for(int i = 1 + (int)_INVALID; i < (int)_MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("month %d = %s\n", i, month_strings[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    /* switch-case based solution */
    for(int i = (int)_INVALID; i <= (int)_MAX; i++)
    {
        const char *name;
        switch(i)
        {
            /* construct switch-cases using macro */
            MONTHS(CASE)
        }
        printf("month %d = %s\n", i, name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
month_strings[2] FEB
month_strings[MAY] MAY

month 1 = JAN
month 2 = FEB
month 3 = MAR
month 4 = APR
month 5 = MAY
month 6 = JUN
month 7 = JUL
month 8 = AUG
month 9 = SEP
month 10 = OCT
month 11 = NOV
month 12 = DEC

month 0 = _INVALID
month 1 = JAN
month 2 = FEB
month 3 = MAR
month 4 = APR
month 5 = MAY
month 6 = JUN
month 7 = JUL
month 8 = AUG
month 9 = SEP
month 10 = OCT
month 11 = NOV
month 12 = DEC
month 13 = _MAX
```

Comment: The OP can't even tell the difference between an enum and an array, and then you think the natural next step is learning X macros?